# Automatically moving UICollectionCells in horizontal direction

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying all the stuffs i could like using UIView to animate but in vain. 
I need the CollectionView Cells should automatically swipe horizontally after every fixed seconds.

Please help me out with this, as this is the only sole reason my app is waiting its release.

I tried this but in vain.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (collectionView == self.myCV) {
        myCollectionView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *xibPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCollectionView" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [xibPath objectAtIndex:0];
        }

//        [myCV performBatchUpdates:^{
//            [self.myCV reloadData];
//        } completion: nil];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
            [self.myCV scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.section inSection:0]
                                        atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                                animated:NO];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"Completed");
        }];

        return cell;



    }
```

**Thank You,**
**Best Regards.**

Comment: You mean the left most cells disappear and new ones appear on the right ?

Comment: how many cell visible in your uicollectionview ?

Comment: @paul : Exactly !!! If you need i can send a demo for the same to have you feel the need.

Comment: @iPatel : Those are coming from webService. Dynamic

Comment: but by default if you do not scroll then maximum how many ??

Comment: @iPatel : initially one cell would be displayed.Then after one second another would come in picture as in we have swipe it horizontally. The idea is to make the cells swipe automatically in horizontal direction.

Comment: @iPatel : If you need, i can send you a demo copy for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your move code is working then use it in timer function with interval of 1 sec as

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

-(void)targetMethod
{

    [self.myCV scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:rowIndex inSection:0]
                      atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                              animated:YES];

    rowIndex=(rowIndex<noOfRows-1)?(rowIndex+1):0;

}
```

OR

This could help u better

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129472/1305001

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap insert/delete/reload operations in a `performBatchUpdates:completion:` block.
eg :

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
} completion: nil];
```

You should then use a timer to call this code periodically. This assumes you also update your data source

Comment: Probably this would reload data. Do i need to include a timer in it. I have never face d animations or timer.Please elaborate

Comment: Hey i did use the above code in my demo app, but the thing is the app is not launching at all.

Comment: You need to periodically call this code with an NSTimer. It should call collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: automatically