# Change built in animation duration of scrollToItemAtIndexPath in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, core-animation

I am running this line of code:

```
self.myCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(myIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
```

It works fine.

What I am trying to figure out is how to change the animation duration. I want to be able to scroll fairly slow but I can't seem to find a way to change the default duration of the animation to the value I want.

Anybody know how to do this?

I tried wrapping that line inside a CATransacation and set a custom transaction animation but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006972/creating-slow-scrolling-to-indexpath-in-uicollectionview

Comment: @NikitaZernov: I tested that method. It does allow me to perform a slow scroll, so I voted your answer up because it has been helpful. However, I was wondering if there is a way to alter the duration of the scrollToItemAtIndexPath call. Thank you