# Animation of scrolling in collectionview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have one one collectionview in that I have 10 images loaded from webservice. I want to autoscroll that imageview from 1st to last position and then last to 1st position continuously whenever that page appears.
I use below method

```
-(void)scrollSlowly 
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 4.0f;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:3.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{

                         [self.CollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(CGFLOAT_MAX ,0)];

                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [self.CollectionView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
}

-(void)scrollSlowlyToPoint 
{
   self.CollectionView.contentOffset = self.scrollingPoint;
    //    Here you have to respond to user interactions or else the scrolling will not stop until it reaches the endPoint.
   if (CGPointEqualToPoint(self.scrollingPoint, self.endPoint))
   {
       [self.scrollingTimer invalidate];
   }
    //    Going one pixel to the right.
   self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(self.scrollingPoint.x+1, self.scrollingPoint.y);
}
```

I want to autoscroll horizontally in Objective-C. thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `- (void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated` ?

Comment: Yes i too use this but it wont give me repetitive slow scrolling... @sourcer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom UICollectionViewCell class, create and connect an outlet for image view.

In .h file:

```
    NSMutableArray *imgArr;
    NSInteger testIndexPath;
```

I guess you can implement the datasource methods for UICollectionView.

In cellForItemAtIndexPath add this line after adding images to the imageview

```
    testIndexPath=indexPath.row;//this will give you the indexPath for cell
```

Now add this two methods in your .m file:

```
   -(void)autoScroll{
    CGFloat point = self.collectionVw.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat lo = point + 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.collectionVw.contentOffset = CGPointMake(lo, 0);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (testIndexPath==8)
    {
        [self autoScrollReverse];
    }
    else{
      [self autoScroll];
    }
  }];
 }

  -(void)autoScrollReverse{
    CGFloat point = self.collectionVw.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat lo = point - 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.collectionVw.contentOffset = CGPointMake(lo, 0);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if(testIndexPath == 0){
        [self autoScroll];
    }else{
       [self autoScrollReverse];

    }

  }];
 }

 //Call [self autoScroll] in your viewDidLoad
```

Comment: i have my imageview in the cell of collectionview....How could i achieve continuous scrolling animation horizontally through above code...couldnt get it..@Akash KR

Comment: follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006972/creating-slow-scrolling-to-indexpath-in-uicollectionview

Comment: That was the same method i used and mentioned above @Akash KR

Comment: Well I have a logic..check for indexPath, if indexPath is equal to count then use this [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES]; else reverse it.

Comment: Can u help me with A code please??Get u what u r telling bt dnt knw how to do it...Because i tried to repeat it bt it wont go from left to right after going to right to left... And also when it goes from right to left  Though images over still it shows me blank scrolling and images vanished @Akash KR

Comment: You might be doing something wrong somewhere..because I have implemented this logic in both swift and objective c and works fine

Comment: Thanx ... I Used Bit Differently But it too worked very well thanx Aussum Thanx For ur efforts @Akash KR

Comment: I m glad that it worked..I did it only for you..@Aashi

Answer (score 0):

Better way to scroll index from top to bottom and bottom to top.

This will move to index 10 means scroll top to bottom

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:9 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

For again scroll bottom to top which move to index 0

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:0.1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

You can also set scrolling from top to bottom in UIVIew animation like above. 
Set the first method in ViewWillAppear and set second method in ViewDidAppear if you need animation for every time page appear

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this one. May be its help to you

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -50);
    }];
    [self delayBy:0.5 code:^{ // call block of code after time interval
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
  }];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: [self delayBy :];    this self method is missing can you add the delay by method .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help solve your problem:

```
int maxDelay = 4;
int delayInSeconds = arc4random() % maxDelay;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your codes//
});
```